# How can I get this function's variable?

Tags: c#, javascript, parsing, web, html-agility-pack

the page has:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
          var articleId = '28';
          var data = window.articleDetailData = {
      "articleData": {
      "id": 20,
      "userId": 73,
      "postId": 29,
      "hurArticleId": 26656,
      "aTitle": "sometext",
      "aTitleShort": "sometext",
      "aSpotText": "“sometext",
      "aSpotTextSort": "“sometext",
      "aContent": "the Text I want",
      "addDate": "2014"
                     },
    "userData": {
     "id": 28049,
    "isUserLiked": false,
   "isUserShared": false
    ......
```

I want to get `aContent` variable of this JavaScript. I tried:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script[contains(text(), 'aContent')]").InnerHtml
  doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("*//script[@type='text/javascript']");
```

and also noises javascript nuget. Couldnt make it happen. I guess this cant be parsed with agilitypack.

How can I start?

Comment: What is the context here? Why are you parsing the content of the page instead of using an ajax call or populating a hidden field for a form post?

Comment: @cadmium Thanks. I cant manipulate the site. site has a newspaper's column which I try to get. Which subjects I should research? "populating hidden field" and "ajax calls" ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use this regex pattern to parse it out:

```
(?<=\"aContent\": \")(.*?)(?=\",)
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like `json` to me. In which case you can do this:

```
var content = data.articleData[0].aContent;
```